# GPU overheating 133 celsius

Tags: ati, overheating, gpu

Recently had to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04. After first restart display keeps shutting down. Checked temp of gpu it was 133 celsius! It's an amd radeon HD2600XT. Software center displays no proprietary drivers in use, but when I check through terminal it says it is using ati 2600xt driver. I'm getting maybe 5 minutes before the display shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your GPU heatsink?  You may want to clean it out with some canned air.   For me, my CPU was idling ~100 degrees C before I opened my case to check it out - the heatsink was completely clogged with dust.

As for your driver issue, I'm not sure why your driver is listed as "ati 2600xt."  I'm using a [Radeon HD 7850] with a the updated proprietary drivers provided through the software center and when I use the terminal to check my driver:

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video
```

Output:

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:52 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:ff600000-ff63ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:ff640000-ff65ffff
```

**driver=radeon**

*edit: Formatting

Comment: I clean my system very often. I double checked and no dust. It works fine on windows less than 65 degrees when watching movie etc. There are no updates or additional drivers in software center.
 description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:43

Comment: My apologies, I meant the addition drivers tab of the "software & updates" app. Well, we can rule out dust... Have you tried the 14.12 (omega) drivers from the AMD website?

Comment: I just installed the 14.12 AMD driver using the generic Linux driver installer on my A10-7300 laptop and the driver is now listed as fglrx_pci. If you successfully install the generic driver that might help you verify the installation. Note: in order to install the generic driver I had to install some dependencies first, they were listed in the /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log